# java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'awaitClose { yourCallbackOrListener.cancel() }' should be used in the end of callbackFlow block

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-flow

I am getting an error the first time the user sign in, however, there is no error the second time the user open the app

from the logcat the `awaiClose` function is triggered. so where is the error come from?!

#### The code

```kotlin
val userIdFlow = callbackFlow {
        val listener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
            Timber.tag("Auth_Util").d("Changed")
            firebaseAuth.currentUser?.let {
                Timber.tag("Auth_Util").d("user exist, id = ${it.uid}")
                trySend(it.uid) // the line mentioned in the error message (AuthUtil.kt:38)
            }
        }

        auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)

        awaitClose {
            Timber.tag("Auth_Util").d("Closed")
            auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
        }
    }
```

#### The Logcat

```
2022-10-13 16:00:11.541  6972-6972  Auth_Util               com.hussienFahmy.myGpaManager        D  Changed
2022-10-13 16:00:11.541  6972-6972  Auth_Util               com.hussienFahmy.myGpaManager        D  user exist, id = g11Hbz2EUWXGSE0WnbcF2nJRUPQ2
2022-10-13 16:00:11.543  6972-6972  Auth_Util               com.hussienFahmy.myGpaManager        D  Closed
2022-10-13 16:00:11.716  6972-6972  AndroidRuntime          com.hussienFahmy.myGpaManager        E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.hussienFahmy.myGpaManager, PID: 6972
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'awaitClose { yourCallbackOrListener.cancel() }' should be used in the end of callbackFlow block.
                                                                                                    Otherwise, a callback/listener may leak in case of external cancellation.
                                                                                                    See callbackFlow API documentation for the details.
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.CallbackFlowBuilder.collectTo(Builders.kt:343)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlow$collectToFun$1.invokeSuspend(ChannelFlow.kt:60)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:69)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resumeUnconfined(DispatchedTask.kt:245)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:161)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.completeResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:513)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.AbstractChannel$ReceiveElement.completeResumeReceive(AbstractChannel.kt:908)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ArrayChannel.offerInternal(ArrayChannel.kt:83)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.AbstractSendChannel.trySend-JP2dKIU(AbstractChannel.kt:155)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ChannelCoroutine.trySend-JP2dKIU(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at com.hussienFahmy.myGpaManager.network.AuthUtil$userIdFlow$1.invokeSuspend$lambda-1(AuthUtil.kt:38)
                                                                                                        at com.hussienFahmy.myGpaManager.network.AuthUtil$userIdFlow$1.$r8$lambda$gz_nO4N2PXNldWwFNxezrd-NGHg(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at com.hussienFahmy.myGpaManager.network.AuthUtil$userIdFlow$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onAuthStateChanged(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzk.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:1)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
                                                                                                        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@1daddb6, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

Comment: Is your collector cancelling the flow when it receives the first item? Where is “Close” in the log coming from?

Comment: "Closed" in the log coming from the `awaitClose` and I use this flow to as mapping to another flows

Comment: Seems like the callback is getting a result some time in the middle of the `awaitClose` block executing. Could it be that the add/remove listeners of firebase are not thread-safe? `callbackFlow` documentation says it requires that they be thread-safe.

Comment: Hey Hussien. Have you solved the issue? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo actually no, I used shared flow instead

Answer (score 1):

```
 awaitClose { channel.close() } instead of awaitClose { cancel() }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same exception.
Adding one line of code to close the channel worked for me.

```
awaitClose {
            Timber.tag("Auth_Util").d("Closed")
            auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
            channel.close()
        }
```